# Multiple sufficient statistics and the factorization theorem

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose you are using the factorization theorem to find a sufficient statistic. Let us say that we have a negative sign in front of $T(x)$. How do you know whether or not to "absorb" a negative sign into a sufficient statistic or any other sign? So instead of $T(x)$ we could have $$\widetilde T(x):=−T(x) \>.$$

For example, suppose you have $$g(T(x)| \theta) = e^{-T(x)}$$ in the factorization theorem. How do you know whether or not to include the negative sign in $T(x)$?

Comment: They are both sufficient and we can say the same thing in a more general context: If $T$ is a sufficient statistic for some parameter $\theta$ than any almost-surely invertible transformation $U = h(T)$ is also sufficient for $\theta$.

Comment: @cardinal: So if $\bar{X}$ is sufficient for $\mu$ then how can $-\bar{X}$ be sufficient for $\mu$? If $\mu$ is known to be positive then how can $-\bar{X}$ be sufficient for $\mu$?

Comment: Hi ross, you should be able to click the "Add comment" link to respond to the comments you see. It might help to think about two things: (**1**) The statement of the Factorization Theorem itself and (**2**) The *definition* of sufficiency vis a vis conditioning on a sufficient statistic. I can post an answer with some more details, if that would help.

Answer (score 2):

A clean way of thinking about this involves a slight change in perspective. Instead of defining estimators to be sufficient, we can define partitions of the sample space to be sufficient. (See e.g. [these notes](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture5.pdf).)

Let $\mathcal{P}=\{B_k\}_{k \in K}$ be a partition of the sample space for some index set $K$. We say that the partition $\mathcal{P}$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if the density $f(x | X \in B_k)$ does not depend on the parameter $\theta$ for any $k \in K$. A nice way to define a partition is through level sets of a statistic $T(x)$. Since the level sets $\{\{X : T(X) = k\}\}_{k \in K} = \{\{X : -T(X) = k\}\}_{k \in -K}$ are the same, this shows that $-T$ is sufficient if and only if $T$ is sufficient. With this perspective, we do not distinguish between $T$ and $-T$, or any other invertible function of $T$.